# Can Java store methods in arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Well I wrote some code and all I was doing was for loops, but changing which method I called. I tried using a for loop so it'd be a bit neater (and out of curiosity to see if it could be done), but it doesn't compile when I do it this way, because it doesn't recognize an item in an array as a method, I think. This is what I have:

```
String[] moveArray = {moveRight,moveDown,moveLeft,moveUp};
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    while (myWumpus.moveArray[i]) {
        myWumpus.moveArray[i];
        generator.updateDisplay();
    }
}
```

When I try compile I get

```
not a statement myWumpus.moveArray[i]();
';' expected myWumpus.moveArray[i]();
```

(It refers to the first statement in the while loop)

So, I think it's maybe because I'm making it an Array of type String? Is there a type Method? Is this at all possible? Any solutions welcome :). Also, I can get it to work using 4 while loops, so you don't need to show me that solution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You cannot store methods directly in arrays. However you can store objects, which implement the same method differently. For example:

```
Mover[] moveArray = {new RightMover(), new DownMover() new LeftMover(), new UpMover() };
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    while (myWumpus.moveArray[i]) {
        moveArray[i].move();
        generator.updateDisplay();
    }
}
```

Comment: A variation is uses enums. You need to pass the object operated on through a parameter in the method call, rather than the constructor.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can store methods in arrays using [Reflection](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/), however it is likely that what you actually want to do in this situation is use [polymorphism](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).

As an example of polymorphism in relation to your problem - say you created an interface as follows:

```
public interface MoveCommand {
    void move();
}
```

You can then create implementations as follows:

```
public class MoveLeftCommand implements MoveCommand {
    public void move() {
        System.out.println("LEFT");
    }
}
```

etc. for the other move options. You could then store these in an `MoveCommand[]` or collection like a `List<MoveCommand>`, and then iterate over the array/collection calling move() on each element, for example:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<MoveCommand> commands = new ArrayList<MoveCommand>();
        commands.add(new MoveLeftCommand());
        commands.add(new MoveRightCommand());
        commands.add(new MoveLeftCommand());

        for (MoveCommand command:commands) {
            command.move();
        }
    }

}
```

Polymorphism is very powerful, and the above is a very simple example of something called the [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). Enjoy the rest of your Wumpus World implementation :)

Answer (score 6):

You can't store methods in arrays in Java, because methods aren't first-class objects in Java. It's a reason some people prefer to use other languages like Python, Scheme, etc.

The work-around is to create an interface which contains one method, then create four classes implementing that interface - the MoveRight, MoveLeft, etc... classes. Then you can store instances of those classes in your array and call them all the same way.

Comment: java.lang.reflect.Method is a first class object, but I agree with the general solution you've presented

Comment: @Brian: Yes, but it's an object representing the method, it isn't actually a method per-se. You can't "call" an instance of Method (you call a method on the instance).

Answer (score 6):

You can't call methods like that. But you can using reflection:

Just change the first line in the while-loop to:

```
Method m = myWumps.getClass().getMethod(moveArray[i]); // if the method is void
m.invoke(myWumps);
```

(you will have to declare/catch a few exceptions)

But you'd better avoid reflection, and use the [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) instead.

Comment: Why it is better to avoid reflection? Is the reflection time consuming or memory overwhelming? The codes above looks very neat.

Answer (score 2):

Updated answer for Java 8 and onwards-

Since the introduction of [lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) and [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) in Java 8, storing various methods in variables is now possible. One main issue is that [arrays don't currently support generic objects in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7131673), which makes storing the methods in arrays less doable. However they can be stored in other data structures like a `List`.

So for some simple examples you can write something like:

```
List<Comparator<String>> stringComparators = new ArrayList<>();
Comparator<String> comp1 = (s1, s2) -> Integer.compare(s1.length(), s2.length());
stringComparators.add(comp1);
```

or

```
List<Consumer<String>> consumers = new ArrayList<>();
Consumer<String> consumer1 = System.out::println;
consumers.add(consumer1);
```

and then loop/iterate through the `List` to get the methods.

Comment: So just to make sure I understand it, this answer is "New answer as of Java 8, the answer is still no"?