# Generic array creation error

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I am trying do something like this:-

```
public static ArrayList<myObject>[] a = new ArrayList<myObject>[2];
```

myObject is a class. I am getting this error:- Generic array creation (arrow is pointing to new.)

Comment: public static ArrayList<MyObject>[] a = new ArrayList[10];

Comment: This is NOT a duplication! That question is about "new E[n]" while this one is "new Generic<E>[n]". Totally different!

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can't have arrays of generic classes. Java simply doesn't support it.

You should consider using a collection instead of an array. For instance,

```
public static ArrayList<List<MyObject>> a = new ArrayList<List<MyObject>();
```

Another "workaround" is to create an auxilliary class like this

```
class MyObjectArrayList extends ArrayList<MyObject> { }
```

and then create an array of `MyObjectArrayList`.

---

Here is a [good article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255/index.html) on why this is not allowed in the language. The article gives the following example of what could happen if it was allowed:

```
List<String>[] lsa = new List<String>[10]; // illegal
Object[] oa = lsa;  // OK because List<String> is a subtype of Object
List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<Integer>();
li.add(new Integer(3));
oa[0] = li; 
String s = lsa[0].get(0);
```

Comment: If it would compile you would be able to create inconsistent collections. (Arrays doesn't work like this, and instead rely on throwing an ArrayStoreException at runtime.) I'll dig up a link for you about it...

Comment: Here's an article. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255/index.html

Comment: If you try to convert the example from the article so arrays are ArrayList then you get an error here: `List<Object> oa = lsa;  // Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<List<String>> to List<Object>` Why don't allow generics arrays doing the same checks? You could activate it with an annotation losing some backward compatibility in that method.

Comment: The same problem here without generics `   String[] x = new String[10];
Object[] y = x;
y[1] = 10; //boxing
String z = x[1];`

Comment: I can't see any difference with this:

Integer [] integerArray=new Integer[20];
Object [] objectArray = integerArray;
objectArray[0]= "Hello world!";
integerArray[0].floatValue();

This code compiles and at runtime throws this Exception:  java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.String

Why?

Answer (score 11):

There is a easier way to create generic arrays than using List.

First, let

```
public static ArrayList<myObject>[] a = new ArrayList[2];
```

Then initialize

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
     a[i] = new ArrayList<myObject>();
}
```

Comment: or, to avoid raw types, `ArrayList<myObject>[] a = (ArrayList<myObject>[])new ArrayList<?>[2];`

Comment: [Using the *raw type* `ArrayList` like this will harm type safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it). For example, you could write `a[0] = new ArrayList<unrelatedObject>();` and it would compile just fine. Anyway, the question does not concern the contents of the array, so I don't see initialization as relevant.

Answer (score 6):

You can do

```
public static ArrayList<myObject>[] a = (ArrayList<myObject>[])new ArrayList<?>[2];
```

or

```
public static ArrayList<myObject>[] a = (ArrayList<myObject>[])new ArrayList[2];
```

(The former is probably better.) Both will cause unchecked warnings, which you can pretty much ignore or suppress by using: @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

Answer (score -1):

if you are trying to declare an arraylist of your generic class you can try:

```
public static ArrayList<MyObject> a = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
```

this will give you an arraylist of myobject (size 10), or if u only need an arraylist of size 2 you can do:

```
public static ArrayList<MyObject> a = new ArrayList<MyObject>(2);
```

or you may be trying to make an arraylist of arraylists:

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<MyObject>> a = new ArrayList<ArrayList<MyObject>>();
```

although im not sure if the last this i said is correct...

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that you use the wrong type of parenthesis. The reason why you can't define an array of generic is **type erasure**.

Plus, declaration of you variable "a" is fragile, it should look this way:

```
List<myObject>[] a;
```

Do not use a concrete class when you can use an interface.