# How does an Entry<K,V> array in java work?

Tags: java, generics, data-structures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generic array creation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131652/generic-array-creation-error)

I'm working on an assignment that deals with an Entry array. I figured out how to create it, but I'm not fully understanding how it works. Why is it that when creating the new Entry array, I don't need to specify the K,V type? If you guys could provide some insight as to how it functions, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
private Entry<K,V>[] data;


data = new Entry[4096];
```

Comment: Are K and V types in your program, or type variables?

Comment: They are types, K represents key and V represents value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create the array with `new Entry[4096]` you are just creating 4096 references, the compiler doesn't care at this point that they are references to `Entry<K,V>` because the  will be removed via type erasure. Remember that generics in java are just a syntatic sugar over the underlying class format. At runtime the generics don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Which part don't you understand? `Entry<K,V>` is a generic type that is parameterized with K and V. You can also use `Entry`, which is the raw type without generics (for backwards compatibility). They are the same after type erasure. Similarly, you can have `Entry<K,V>[]` and `Entry[]`. They can be converted between each other, but it will be an unchecked conversion.

In fact, you *can't* specify specific parameters in the component type of an array creation. You must do either `new Entry[4096]` or `new Entry<?,?>[4096]`. So an unchecked conversion is unavoidable.