# Java Sudoku: Generic Array Creation

Tags: java, arrays, generics, creation, sudoku

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java how to: Generic Array creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/java-how-to-generic-array-creation)
>   [Generic array creation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131652/generic-array-creation-error)

```
private ArrayList<Integer>[][] potentialList = new ArrayList<Integer>[9][9];
```

Someone, please explain to me why this statement gives me a:

```
--------------------Configuration: <Default>--------------------  
SolveSudoku.java:31: error: generic array creation  
private ArrayList<Integer>[][] potentialList = new ArrayList<Integer>[9][9];  
//The error is on the "n" of new ArrayList.

Process completed.
```

Comment: Why not simply `private Integer[][] potentialList = new Integer[9][9];`?  Or to put that another way, why not simply use an array?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, where thousands of software professionals have answered hundreds of thousands of questions.  Please search through them before asking your own.

Answer (score 0):

We don't know what you want to do, maybe:

```
private ArrayList<Integer[][]> potentialList = new ArrayList<Integer[][]> ();
```

This would be a list of 2dim-Integer-Arrays.