# Can't create a Object Array of Generic Class in Java

Tags: java, object, generics

In the Node Class constructor, I am trying to initialize `childArray` and `dataArray` which are objects based on Generic class themselves.

```
private class Node<type extends Comparable<type>> {
        public Node<type>[] childArray;
        public DataItem<type>[] dataArray;
        public int dataCount; //No. of data elements in the node
        public int childCount; //No. of child elements under it
        public Node<type> parent;
        private static final int ORDER = 4;

        public Node() {

            childArray = (Node<type>[]) new Object[ORDER];
            dataArray = (DataItem<type>[]) new Object[ORDER - 1];
            dataCount = 0;
            childCount = 0;
        }
}
```

I am getting the following error when I try to compile:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [LTree234$Node;
    at Tree234$Node.<init>(Tree234.java:37)
    at Tree234.<init>(Tree234.java:149)
    at Tree234.main(Tree234.java:266)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

The complete code can be found at:
https://gist.github.com/stirredo/2a40d48021a8b9e14959

How do I overcome this problem?

I know there are many questions with the exception found in my problem but I am not able to apply them to my problem.

Comment: `Node` is an `Object` but `Object` isn't a `Node`

Comment: Wait, I'm not so sure about that duplicate... Duplicate is about `T[]`, this one isn't... My mistake. Duplicate would apply if you wanted to make a `type[]`.

Comment: Why not just use the raw types for the arrays?

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to cast an `Object[]` to a `Node[]` without the `Object[]` having ever been a `Node[]`. Presumably you put the cast on it because `childArray = new Object[ORDER]` was giving you `incompatible types` at compile time. Similarly, the `ClassCastException` is due to the two failing to resolve to a "compatible" state (at runtime).

So you want it to be `childArray = new Node<T>[ORDER];` which is [also not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131652/generic-array-creation-error). In short, you should use some form of [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html)

```
class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> {
  private Collection<Node<T>> children;
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you do `(Node<T>[]) new Node[])` and suppress the warning? (if you can't use collections, that is)

Comment: I'd just drop the cast altogether in that case and let the access control methods handle `<T>`.

Comment: That's true... Isn't that what the Java collections do?

Answer (score 1):

```
childArray = (Node<type>[])new Node[ORDER];
```

or

```
childArray = (Node<type>[])new Node<?>[ORDER];
```