# Representing array of lists

Tags: java, arrays, list

This seems like basic question, but it has really confused me. I ma trying to represent the adjacency list of a graph. I have two questions :

```
public class Graph
{
    private final int V;
    private List<Integer>[] adj;

    public Graph(int V)
    {
        this.V = V;
        this.adj = (List<Integer>[]) new LinkedList[V];  // this works
    }
}
```

**Question 1**: when I do the below, it gives an error saying

```
Array type expected; found: 'java.util.LinkedList<java.lang.Integer>'
this.adj = (List<Integer>[]) new LinkedList<Integer>()[V];
```

I am creating a List of Integer arrays, right ?

**Question 2**: when I do this, it again gives an error saying generic array creation:

```
this.adj = (List<Integer>[]) new LinkedList<Integer>[V];
```

What is the problem with the last two approaches ? i think the first one is more correct.

Comment: What type is `this.adj`?

Comment: private List<Integer>[] adj;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In (1), your expression is being parsed as

```
(new LinkedList<Integer>())[V]
```

which is attempting to index a freshly-created `LinkedList`, hence the error.

In (2), you are trying to make an array of generics. [You can't do this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7131652/1204143). Instead, consider using some container type (like an `ArrayList<List<Integer>>`).

Comment: In(2), how am I creating an array of Generics. I am creating an array Of Integers.

Comment: You are not making an array of integers, you're making an array of lists of integers. The latter are generics.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create an array of list of integer. That means each index can have multiple count. So, you need to initialize each index.

```
public Graph(int v)
    {
        V = v;
        adj = new List<int>[v];
        for (int i = 0; i < v; ++i)
            adj[i] = new List<int>();
    }
```