# JAVA: "Generic Array creation" Error while creating array

Tags: java, arrays

When I create array of LinkedList (of Integers) like this,

```
new LinkedList<Integer>[V];
```

it gives me error saying "**Generic Array creation**"

but when I create array like this

```
new LinkedList[V];
```

it works fine.

What is this error and what's going wrong here ?

Comment: What's the problem? Creating an array of a generic type is not allowed.

Comment: Generic creation of array is not allowed in JAVA.
See this post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131652/generic-array-creation-error/23034391]

Comment: Could you please tell me what's the difference between the 2

Comment: Please visit the link. Its well explained. If you have further doubt post a new question.

Comment: @SubhasishBhattacharjee you can create an array with a generic element type: it just has to be reifiable, e.g. `new ArrayList<?>[V]` is allowed.