# Array index out of Bound Exception handling inside try catch

Tags: java, exception

getting an array index out of a bound exception in below code.
I have tried to put the error line inside try-catch, putting try catch also throwing an error in eclipse. 
can anyone pls tell me what I am doing wrong.

Error:

```
"Multiple markers at this line
- Syntax error on token "try", invalid 
 Modifiers
- Syntax error, insert "}" to complete 
 Block"
```

With try catch:

```
try {
    public hashMapimpl() {
        table =new Entry[5];
    }}catch(Exception e)
  {
        e.getMessage();
  }
```

Complete code:

```
import java.util.Map.Entry;
class hashMapimpl<K,V>  {   
    static int capacity=5;
    private Entry<K,V> [] table;

    static class Entry<K, V>{
        K key;
        V value;
        Entry<K,V> next;

        public Entry(K key,V value, Entry<K,V> next)
            {
            this.key=key;
            this.value=value;
            this.next=next;
        }

    }

    public hashMapimpl() {
        table =new Entry[capacity];
    }

    public void put(K newKey, V data) {
        if(newKey==null) {
            return;
        }
        int hash=hash(newKey);
        Entry<K,V> newentry = new Entry<K,V>(newKey,data,null);
        if(table[hash]==null)
            table[hash]=newentry;
        else {
            Entry<K,V> previous =null;

            Entry<K,V> current=table[hash];     
        while(current!=null)
        {
            if(current.key.equals(newKey))
            {
                if(previous==null) {
                    newentry.next=current.next;
                    table[hash]=newentry;
                    return;}
                else {
                    newentry.next=current.next;
                    table[hash]=newentry;
                    return;
                }
            }
            previous=current;
            current=current.next;
        }
        previous.next=newentry;
        }
    }


    public V get(K key) {
        int hash=hash(key);
        if(table[hash]==null) {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            Entry<K,V> temp=table[hash];
            while(temp!=null)
            {
                if(temp.key.equals(key))
                    temp=temp.next;
                    return temp.value;

            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void display()
    {

        for(int i=0;i<capacity;i++) {
            if(table[i]!=null) {
                Entry<K,V> e=table[i];
                while(e!=null)
                {
                    System.out.println(e.key);
                    System.out.println(e.value);
                    e=e.next;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private int hash(K Key) {
        return Math.abs(Key.hashCode());
    }

public static class hashmap_main{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        hashMapimpl<Integer,Integer> h1 = new hashMapimpl<Integer,Integer>();
        h1.put(2, 4);
        h1.put(4, 0);
        h1.put(23, 9);
        h1.put(1, 8);

        System.out.println(h1.get(23));

    }
}
}
```

Comment: why its throwing out of bound exception .. I have checked the insertion and array limit, it's not exceeding the capacity

Comment: I'm pretty sure the hashcode of an object can be greater than 4.

Comment: Please add stack trace of the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` you are getting to the question.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for a try / catch is like this:

```
try {
    // statements

} catch(Exception e) {
    // more statements
}
```

Your code *appears* to have a constructor declaration

```
public hashMapimpl() {
    table = new Entry[5];
}
```

where there should be statements.   That's not valid Java.  And it makes little sense to me.

Either way, the Java compiler is rightly telling you that the syntax is wrong ... albeit without explaining why<sup>1</sup>.

It is possible that you mean this:

```
public hashMapimpl() {
    try {
        table = new Entry[capacity];
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    } 
}
```

but that's a bad idea too.

Q: What is going to happen if you get an exception?

A: The constructor is going to print an error message ... and then continue as if nothing had gone wrong.  And that is going to leave you with a `null` in the `table` field ... which will most likely trigger NPEs a bit later.

The correct way to solve this is to figure out **why** you are getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception, and fix the *cause* of the exception.

Hint: what is the *actual* value of `capacity` when you create the array??

---

<sup>1 - Unfortunately, a compiler can only produce a meaningful error message if it understood what you *meant* by that.  Compilers typically can't figure out what you (probably) mean if the syntax is too messed up.</sup>

Comment: you are right i had checked already the capacity value i already declared capacity =4 and adding only four keys to array ,, it is under the bound but still i am getting ...that why is there any leak in the code ?

Comment: do you know how to check the internal impl of hashmap from eclipse ?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: I mean to say can I find all the get, put ..etc methods inside java.util.hashmap package,to check internal working of hashmap

Comment: It is in the source code.  You can find it by googling; e.g. for "java.util.HashMap source code".   Or you can clone an entire OpenJDK source code tree from https://openjdk.java.net/

Answer (score -1):

You can't have arrays of generic classes. Java simply doesn't support it. See this answer for using collections as a alternative.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7131673/7260643

Comment: you mean to say i can not declare the array as "private Entry<K,V> [] table;".??

Comment: what you mean Stephen