# Java ArrayList of integers and arrays of generics

Tags: java

The [2022 edition of the Princeton Review's "AP Computer Science A Prep"](https://a.co/d/bW1mwTX) includes an example problem with the following code:

```java
public class Screen {
    private ArrayList<int>[] data;
.
.
.
}
```

1. Was there any version of Java for which `ArrayList<int>` is a valid construction? My understanding is that in all cases that would need to be `ArrayList<Integer>`. With Java 17 and 21 (which are what happen to be installed on my system), `ArrayList<int>` produces an `unexpected type` error.
2. If we define this as `ArrayList<Integer>[] data`, how do we instantiate it properly? The obvious solution would be `data = new ArrayList<Integer>[10]` (assuming we want 10 ArrayLists), but that fails with a `generic array creation`, because Java [doesn't support arrays of generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131652/generic-array-creation-error).

I am trying to understand if there is a mistake in this book or if my understanding of Java is simply lacking. Thanks!

Comment: If we give the author(s) the benefit of the doubt and assume this is a typo, perhaps they meant to write `ArrayList<int[]>` (which would be valid because arrays are reference types, not primitives).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Was there any version of Java for which `ArrayList<int>` is a valid construction?

No. Never. Generics cannot contain primitive types, nor was there even a java version where you could (and *if* you ever could, wouldn't you think that would have been a huge deal, specifically, its removal? Java rarely breaks backwards compatibility!)

> If we define this as `ArrayList<Integer>[] data`, how do we instantiate it properly?

**impossible**. You **cannot** instantiate it properly<sup>2</sup>. There is no point whatsoever to having an array of a non-primitive type. `List<List<Integer>>` is superior in all ways to a `List<Integer>[]`. So, just make that - a list of a list.

> I am trying to understand if there is a mistake in this book

A casual web search doesn't find the specific contents of this book, nor does the link you provide lead to it (no doubt it'll be hard to find, I assume its copyrighted and the authors don't want it to be easily accessible without paying for it). The key content I was looking for there is some context in that chapter explaining *why* this isn't possible, or that this is a bad idea, or, well, anything to indicate that the problems you are highlighting here are the very point the book was trying to make.

If that's not in the book and they are either claiming that this is valid java, or they are claiming it is somehow relevant, then it's a crap book. Perhaps that's the reason I can't find it online :)

To summarize:

1. You cannot make `List<int>`. You cannot do so now. You never were able to.<sup>1</sup>
2. `List<Integer>[]` is idiotic. No code should ever write this. Arrays have all sorts of downsides. They have very few upsides; the upsides they have are irrelevant in this scenario which is why arrays do exist (partly as low-level 'glue' - the implementation of `java.util.ArrayList` is written in java, and uses an `Object[]` internally. Something has to - and partly because `int[]` really is currently vastly more efficient both in space and time, versus a `List<Integer>`). Hence, silly idea that you should never write, and thus any book that does a deep dive on how to make it work anyway, is just.. weird. That should be a fine lesson for someone who is in their 15th year of their java career, if ever. It's like teaching a racing car driver about the transmission in the original Ford Model T. It's car related. Whatever lessons are to be had from it are completely irrelevant, though.

---

[1] *Possibly* in JDK25+ or so you *might* be able to - Project Valhalla is the OpenJDK team that is attempting to find a way to create data types that code like standard reference types but perform and act like primitives, and as part of that, possibly `List<int>` can be turned into a thing. Especially this part (trying to treat `int` as merely the value-type variant of `j.l.Integer`, and making these types work in generics) is what Project Valhalla hasn't really tackled yet and possibly never will - there are significant backwards compatibility issues. Such as how the `j.u.List` interface has the method `remove(int x)`, which removes the object at index `int x`, as well as the method `remove(Object o)`, which scans through the list, comparing each object in the list to `o` - once it finds a match (`item.equals(o)` is `true`), that is removed, and the `remove` method returns. Aside from the problems that e.g. `remove()`, `contains()` etc take as argument `Object` and not `E` (because you CAN ask a list of apples if some given pear is in it. The answer is very trivially: No, but, it's not a non-sequitur question, hence why that choice was made) - trying to unify generics and primitives means both signatures are now `remove(int)` which obviously cannot be. Just one of a million reasons why this is the trickiest part of Valhalla and might never happen. If you'd like to read more about it, or just keep up to date on updates on this, [check JEP 218](https://openjdk.org/jeps/218). This edit brought to you by a comment from @M.Justin :)

[2] 'properly' is a subjective term. I define it here as I expect most would: With zero warnings from the compiler and no need for `@SuppressWarnings`. Possibly also defined as: Without breaking the very promises arrays make - which is also impossible (one 'promise' is that an array can, *at runtime*, tell you its component type, via `arrRef.getClass().getComponentType()`. This, trivially, can only tell you: I am an array of `ArrayList` references - it cannot tell you `ArrayList<Integer>`. Only `ArrayList`.

Comment: Work is being done to support primitive generic types such as `ArrayList<int>` in [JEP 218: Generics over Primitive Types](https://openjdk.org/jeps/218).  But this hasn't even graduated to incubator status, so when or if it'll finally be available is up in the air.

Comment: I have added a link to JEP218 in the section about some far off future where _possibly_ you might be able to make these things. Thanks, @M.Justin!

Comment: “Arrays have all sorts of downsides” might be a little extreme.  Primitive arrays are often useful.  And even object arrays have at least one important advantage:  casting to a (non-generic) object array type is safe.

Comment: @VGR I explicitly call out that arrays-of-primitives have plenty of fine use cases. They STILL have 'all sorts of downsides' - just, in plenty of plausible cases enough upsides to balance out the pain. Not so for non-primitive component type arrays. The advantage you name is not important.

Answer (score 2):

1. *`ArrayList<int>` is a valid construction?*
   - **No**. In Java, Generic type doesn't work for primitive data types.
2. *How do we instantiate `ArrayList<Integer>[]` properly?*
   - You can do it in the following way -

   `List<Integer>[] a = new ArrayList[10];`

   **Java doesn't allow you to create generic array**, but you can simply create array of Object, which in this case ArrayList. Though this will give you warning as **unchecked or unsafe operations**, but you can overcome that by `@SuppressWarnings` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Generics over primitive types are not yet allowed in Java, so `ArrayList<int>` is currently not legal or supported.

Work is being done to eventually support this sort of generics usage in [JEP 218: Generics over Primitive Types](https://openjdk.org/jeps/218).  This JEP was created in 2014, and it's unclear when or if this will graduate to being a production-ready feature.

> ## JEP 218: Generics over Primitive Types
>
> ### Summary
>
> Extend generic types to support the specialization of generic classes and interfaces over primitive types.