# Can I use the method if the object is held by an multidimensional array?

Tags: java, object, jcombobox, jtextfield, multidimensional-array

I saw some post quite similar but did not hit spot on.

I was thinking something like this:

```
Object[][] test = {
          {"Name", new JTextField()},
          {"Gender", new JComboBox()}
}
```

I tried something like this but i cannot use the method of the JTextField or the JComboBox. How do I instantiate this depending on there 1-index? Is this possible?

Comment: You might want to store your components in a Map instead of an array.

Comment: @assylias +1 for more applicable data structure

Comment: a similar post with a nice solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172718/can-java-store-methods-in-arrays

Comment: Map?.. im not that expert yet in java, so let me take a look at it. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 4):

If you know for sure what it is, you can cast it when you get it out, like this

```
JComboBox box = (JComboBox)(test[1][1]);
box.whatever();
```

However, instead of using an `Object[][]`, why not just make a class?

```
class UIWidgets {
    JTextField name;
    JComboBox gender;
}
```

Comment: what if, we assuming that in the array it can be any objects anytime. So my casting cannot be static right? a class? What i'm really trying to do is to pass this Object[][], what ever the contents may be, and then create them. Like i said my casting cannot be constant considering the different possibilities. (try catch could be) but is there other ways to approach this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast first before you can access methods specific to the type, since Java sees them all as instances of `Object`:

```
((JTextField)test[0][1]).CallMethodHere();
```

Or alternately:

```
JTextField tf = (JTextField)test[0][1];
// do something with tf
```

Comment: what if, we assuming that in the array it can be any objects anytime. So my casting cannot be static right? what other way to i approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
((JTextField) test[0][1]).setText("someText");
```